# Getting all checkboxes checked

Tags: jquery, checkbox, html-table

I've been experiencing lots of problems with my function.
function supposed to check all Checkboxes if checkbox in the first row is checked and the opposite.
This is what I wrote:

```
$("#meetingspanel").on("click", ":checkbox", function() {
  if ($(this).parent().parent() == ($("tr:first"))) {
    chboxcondition++;
    if (chboxcondition % 2 !=0) {
      $(":checkbox").each(function() {
        $(this).attr('checked', true);
      });
    } else {
      $(":checkbox").each(function() {
        $(this).attr('checked', false);
      });
    }
  } else
    return false;
});
```

It works by checking all of them and unchecking. Problem is it checks and unchecks all no matter what checkbox I press, even the fifth, I want only the first in the first row.

This is how the checkbox creating goes

```
$("<td style=border:0px><input type='checkbox' id='btncb'></td>").insertAfter($("td:nth-child(6)"));
```

Comment: $(":checkbox").each , this will get EVERY checkbox... maybe something like this will work: $("tr:first:checkbox")

Comment: why don't you add this event listener only to the first checkbox, saving yourself all the distinguishing trouble inside the event listener?

Comment: how does your markup look like

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you are placing the checkbox you want to check(to check all check boxes or not)  in same panel.

solution, place the every other check box in a div say 'checkBoxDiv' and  us ethat div  identifier in the function above. That takes care the controlling checkbox is not affected

Comment: not good cause ive some build for that checkbox inside a table, here it is:
 $("<td style=border:0px><input type='checkbox' id='btncb'></td>").insertAfter($("td:nth-child(6)"));
and it works from another function